# Symfony form gets messy when calling getObject() in form configuration

Tags: forms, configuration, symfony1

I have a Strain model that has a *belongsTo* relationship with a Sample model, i. e. a strain belongs to a sample.

I am configuring a hidden field in the StrainForm `configure()` method this way:

```
$defaultId = (int)$this->getObject()->getSample()->getTable()->getDefaultSampleId();
$this->setWidget('sample_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array('default' => $defaultId)));
```

Whenever I create a new Strain, the `$form->save()` fails. The debug toolbar revealed that it tries to save a Sample object first and I do not know why.

However, if I retrieve the default sample ID using the table it works like a charm:

```
$defaultId = (int)Doctrine_Core::getTable('Sample')->getDefaultSampleId();
$this->setWidget('sample_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array('default' => $defaultId)));
```

My question here is what can be happening with the `getObject()->getSample()...` sequence of methods that causes the `StrainForm` to think it has to save a `Sample` object instead of `Strain`.

I tried to debug with xdebug but I cannot came up with a clear conclusion.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getSample` its creating a Sample instance. This is automatically attached to the Strain object, thus when you save you also save the Sample.

An altenrative to calling getSample would be to chain through Strain object to the Sample table since i assume youre only doing this so your not hardcodeing the Sample's name in related form:

```
// note Sample is the alias not necessarily the Model name
$defaultId = Doctrine_Core::getTable($this->getObject()->getTable()->getRelation('Sample')->getModel())->getDefaultId();
```

Comment: @prodigitalson Is that stated anywhere in Symfony documentation or API? The attaching consequence thing I mean...

Comment: It would be in the Doctrine Documentation its not a symfony specific thing. But i dont recall if its stated there i think i remember picking that up in the code. It actually makes snese... if youre calling $someObject->getRealatedObject() you would expect the new related object ot be put in the graph because you called it from its relation.

Comment: @prodigitalson It could make sense or not, we can discuss it another time. But I think it definitely has to be in Symfony docs, since it is related with sfForm subclasses, not Doctrine objects.

Comment: Why would it be in the symfony docs? The issue is in doctrine not symfony.. getObject gets a Doctrine_Record that is bound to the form. when you call sfFormDoctrine::save() it then calls Doctrine_Record::save(); which is where the sample saving comes into play because it registered in the graph to the Strain object attached to the form.

Comment: @prodigitalson IMHO because `getObject()` is a method of sfFormObject documented in Symfony API, no matter if it is subclassed later by sfDoctrineForm or sfPropelForm. At least a word of caution pointing to ORM documentation would be appreciated, because you could be using another ORM that has not that attachment behaviour

Comment: right but its a function of how doctrine operates not how symfony operates. They symfony portion of the behavior is consistent you call sfForm::getObject it returns the object the form is bound to, creating it if it doesnt exist yet. ITs that you then called Strain::getSample which is Doctrine_Record specific in it behavior that caused all the head scratching. I dunno i guess i just dont agree. I dont think the sf docs need to call out the internal behavior of doctrine unless it specifically applies to how an integration point which this doesnt really. anyhow glad you got it working :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1020/discussion-between-elitalon-and-prodigitalson)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution probably falls over because you can't use getObject() on a new form (as at that stage the object simply doesn't exist).

Edit: Why don't you pass the default Sample in via the options array and then access it from within the form class via $this->getOption('Sample') (if I remember correctly)?

Comment: Thats not true, it creates a new object if the object doesnt exist.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But then at that stage it won't be assigned to any sample, right?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure its going to attach it. Then when save is called it figures out what order to save in via the object graph.